# AsyncTask Android PHP getting "<<application>> stopped working"

Tags: java, php, android, android-asynctask

I am using AsynTask to send data to php and receive a name to print but it showed the following error.  How can I fix this?

**LOGCAT**

```
12-29 21:38:27.588: W/dalvikvm(1283): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at com.example.myweb.toPHP.getUserLoggedIn(toPHP.java:99)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at com.example.myweb.toPHP.doInBackground(toPHP.java:67)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at com.example.myweb.toPHP.doInBackground(toPHP.java:1)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-29 21:38:27.748: E/AndroidRuntime(1283):     ... 4 more
```

This is my Java code to send data to PHP:

**toPHP.java**

```
package com.example.myweb;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class toPHP extends AsyncTask{
    final MainActivity main;

    public toPHP(MainActivity main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    private JSONParser jsonParser;
    String email,password;
    EditText emailBox;
    EditText passwordBox;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();
        TextView textV1 = (TextView)main.findViewById(R.id.textV1);
        textV1.setText("Reaching em!!");        
    }   
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... v) {


        //main = (MainActivity)parameters[0];
        main.afterEffect("sending...");
        emailBox = (EditText) main.findViewById(R.id.email);
        passwordBox = (EditText) main.findViewById(R.id.password);
        email = emailBox.getText().toString();
        password = passwordBox.getText().toString();            
        JSONObject json = null;
        main.afterEffect("sending2...");
        try {
            json = getUserLoggedIn(email, password);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace(); //9b6a45925f32c3ce5a8b3413605b16d6
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;        
     }


    public JSONObject getUserLoggedIn(String email,String password) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException{
        JSONObject json = null;
        /*
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost  post = new HttpPost("http://localhost/testand.php");
        */
        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        //post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
        //HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        //HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        //if (resEntity != null) {

            //String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();

            json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://localhost/testand.php", pairs);



        //}     
        return json;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        String myName="";
        try {
            myName = json.getString("name");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String str = myName + ", Welcome to Socionet. :) ";
        main.afterEffect(str);
    }

}
```

The following is my main Java code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myweb;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button button;
    EditText emailBox;
    EditText passwordBox;
    String emailId;
    String passwordId;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login1);
        emailBox   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        passwordBox   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

       button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()   {             
           public void onClick(View v)  {               
            try {
               new toPHP(MainActivity.this).execute();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();                    
            }               
           }  
         });
       }
    public void afterEffect(String str){

        TextView textV1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textV1);
        textV1.setText(str);        

    }
}
```

The following is my JSON Parser code:

**JSONParser.java**

```
package com.example.myweb;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
    }
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List params) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** This is my LOGCAT2 response after savchak's fix:

**LOGCAT2**

```
12-30 06:44:19.664: W/System.err(777): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost refused
12-30 06:44:19.744: W/System.err(777):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
12-30 06:44:19.744: W/System.err(777):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
12-30 06:44:19.744: W/System.err(777):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
12-30 06:44:19.744: W/System.err(777):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
12-30 06:44:19.754: W/System.err(777):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-30 06:44:19.764: W/System.err(777):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-30 06:44:19.764: W/System.err(777):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
12-30 06:44:19.764: W/System.err(777):  at com.example.myweb.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:33)
12-30 06:44:19.774: W/System.err(777):  at com.example.myweb.toPHP.getUserLoggedIn(toPHP.java:99)
12-30 06:44:19.784: W/System.err(777):  at com.example.myweb.toPHP.doInBackground(toPHP.java:67)
12-30 06:44:19.784: W/System.err(777):  at com.example.myweb.toPHP.doInBackground(toPHP.java:1)
12-30 06:44:19.804: W/System.err(777):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-30 06:44:19.804: W/System.err(777):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-30 06:44:19.804: W/System.err(777):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-30 06:44:19.814: W/System.err(777):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-30 06:44:19.824: W/System.err(777):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-30 06:44:19.824: W/System.err(777):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-30 06:44:19.824: W/System.err(777): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
12-30 06:44:19.844: W/System.err(777):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
12-30 06:44:19.864: W/System.err(777):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
12-30 06:44:19.864: W/System.err(777):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
12-30 06:44:19.864: W/System.err(777):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
12-30 06:44:19.864: W/System.err(777):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
12-30 06:44:19.874: W/System.err(777):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
12-30 06:44:19.884: W/System.err(777):  ... 16 more
12-30 06:44:19.934: W/System.err(777): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
12-30 06:44:20.004: W/System.err(777):  at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
12-30 06:44:20.004: W/System.err(777):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
12-30 06:44:20.004: W/System.err(777):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
12-30 06:44:20.025: W/System.err(777):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
12-30 06:44:20.025: W/System.err(777):  ... 21 more
12-30 06:44:20.025: E/Buffer Error(777): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
12-30 06:44:20.034: E/JSON Parser(777): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Comment: Please mark line# 99 in `toPHP.java`

Comment: `json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://localhost/testand.php", pairs);` @Rohit5k2

Comment: still wont work! @Rohit5k2

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `jsonParser` is always null, therefore throwing the NullPointerException during `doInBackground`.

Answer (score 0):

Your jsonParser field is null reference. You should init with some object.

Comment: private JSONParser jsonParser; - this field is always null reference. write 
    private JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
It should help.
And learn some more java:)

Answer (score 0):

### SOLVED

Orest Savchak and a little of mine helped me.

Things i did to work it

- `JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser(); //in toPHP.java`
- `http//localhost/testand.php` to `http//myipadress/testand.php`
- edited apache hppd conf file to `allow all from`